How to understand the definition of a const 'sql' in vercel/postgres package
I'm new on Nextjs. I saw a weird usage const invoiceCountPromise = sqlSELECT COUNT(*) FROM invoices; when I was studying the official dashboard-app.
Could you please explain how it works? I just have a very basic knowledge of TS. This is too advanced for me. thank you.
This is the index.d.ts file:
import { ClientConfig, PoolConfig, ClientBase, QueryResultRow, QueryResult, Client, Pool } from '@neondatabase/serverless';
export { Client, FieldDef, Pool, Query, QueryArrayConfig, QueryArrayResult, QueryConfig, QueryParse, QueryResult, QueryResultBase, QueryResultRow } from '@neondatabase/serverless';

type Primitive = string | number | boolean | undefined | null;

type ConfigItemsToOmit = 'user' | 'database' | 'password' | 'host' | 'port';
type VercelPostgresClientConfig = Omit<ClientConfig, ConfigItemsToOmit>;
type VercelPostgresPoolConfig = Omit<PoolConfig, ConfigItemsToOmit>;
interface VercelClientBase extends ClientBase {
    sql: <O extends QueryResultRow>(strings: TemplateStringsArray, ...values: Primitive[]) => Promise<QueryResult<O>>;
}
interface VercelPoolClient extends VercelClientBase {
    release: (err?: Error | boolean) => void;
}

declare class VercelClient extends Client {
    /**
     * A template literal tag providing safe, easy to use SQL parameterization.
     * Parameters are substituted using the underlying Postgres database, and so must follow
     * the rules of Postgres parameterization.
     * @example
     * ```ts
     * const pool = createClient();
     * const userId = 123;
     * await client.connect();
     * const result = await pool.sql`SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ${userId}`;
     * // Equivalent to: await pool.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1', [id]);
     * await client.end();
     * ```
     * @returns A promise that resolves to the query result.
     */
    sql<O extends QueryResultRow>(strings: TemplateStringsArray, ...values: Primitive[]): Promise<QueryResult<O>>;
}
declare function createClient(config?: VercelPostgresClientConfig): VercelClient;

declare class VercelPool extends Pool {
    Client: typeof VercelClient;
    private connectionString;
    constructor(config: VercelPostgresPoolConfig);
    /**
     * A template literal tag providing safe, easy to use SQL parameterization.
     * Parameters are substituted using the underlying Postgres database, and so must follow
     * the rules of Postgres parameterization.
     * @example
     * ```ts
     * const pool = createPool();
     * const userId = 123;
     * const result = await pool.sql`SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ${userId}`;
     * // Equivalent to: await pool.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1', [id]);
     * ```
     * @returns A promise that resolves to the query result.
     */
    sql<O extends QueryResultRow>(strings: TemplateStringsArray, ...values: Primitive[]): Promise<QueryResult<O>>;
    connect(): Promise<VercelPoolClient>;
    connect(callback: (err: Error, client: VercelPoolClient, done: (release?: any) => void) => void): void;
}
declare function createPool(config?: VercelPostgresPoolConfig): VercelPool;

type ConnectionStringType = 'pool' | 'direct';
declare function postgresConnectionString(type?: ConnectionStringType): string | undefined;

declare const sql: VercelPool & (<O extends QueryResultRow>(strings: TemplateStringsArray, ...values: Primitive[]) => Promise<QueryResult<O>>);
declare const db: VercelPool & (<O extends QueryResultRow>(strings: TemplateStringsArray, ...values: Primitive[]) => Promise<QueryResult<O>>);

export { VercelClient, VercelClientBase, VercelPool, VercelPoolClient, VercelPostgresClientConfig, VercelPostgresPoolConfig, createClient, createPool, db, postgresConnectionString, sql };


The definition is so complicated and I have never seen the same usage before:
declare const sql: VercelPool & (<O extends QueryResultRow>(strings: TemplateStringsArray, ...values: Primitive[]) => Promise<QueryResult<O>>);



It's called a tagged template. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates It's basically just a fancy function-call syntax that allows the sql function to receive more info about interpolations instead of just the string itself.
